# Javascript/Jquery unexpected }

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax-error

My chrome console gives this error:

```
  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } server.js:11
```

Here's the code:

```
$(function(){
var servers = "http://site-with-json.com/example"

  $.getJSON(servers, function (serverData) {
      $.each(serverData.serverList, function() {
          $.each(this, function(k, v) {
              if (k == "serverName") 
                  {
                    $( "#browser" ).append( '<div class="server">'+v'</div>' )
                    }
              });
        });
    });
});
```

Where the json looks like this:

```
{
  "serverList": [
    {
      "serverName": "Server 1",
      "online": true
    },
    {
      "serverName": "Server 2",
      "online": false
    }
  ]
}
```

Any idea what the error could be? Thanks.

Comment: Also, consider using strict equality operators: `===` instead of `==`.

Comment: I don't think I'll do that, very used to `==`. But thanks for telling me, might help in the future.

Comment: It's not relevant in this scenario anyway, but handy to know if you do need to check the type as well as the value.

Comment: @Mazey - remeber that strict equality `===` is different than loose `==`. Quote from MDN: `It's pretty much never a good idea to use loose equality, ever.` [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_when_to_use_them)

Comment: @kamituel:  I agree with the overall principle, but there are some very cases where `==` is very useful. Let's not forget that MDN is a wiki. What was injected is someone's opinion in an oddly phrased sentence, where they start off by saying "pretty much never", but then end with "ever". Hard to take such a sentence too seriously.

Comment: @user2736012 - sure, it's not prohibited to use `==`, but it's a good practice not to. If you're looking for a better authority on that subject, this is a quote from N. Zakas' "Professional JavaScript for Web Developers": `Because of the type conversion issues with the equal and not-equal operators, it is recommended to use identically equal and not identically equal instead. This helps to maintain data type integrity throughout your code.`.

Comment: Just a hunch, but maybe the problem is that you have an Unexpected token } at server.js:11.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a missing `+` in the following line after `srvname`

```
$( "#browser" ).append( '<div class="server">'+srvname+'</div>' );
```

Also as @smerny pointed out you have to replace srvname with `v` as there is no variable called `srvname`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I accidentally removed the + (as before there was +v+defDivs+).

Answer (score 4):

Check this line

```
 $( "#browser" ).append( '<div class="server">'+srvname'</div>' )
```

It should be:

```
 $( "#browser" ).append( '<div class="server">'+srvname+'</div>' )
```

Also, I dont see `srvname` declared in your code

Comment: you're right, it looks to me like `srvname` should be replaced with `v`.

Comment: Well spotted.  All these answers and no-one else saw that!